# Using RestAPI to get linked changesets after branch merge

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

For the sake of this question we have two branches in our team project; QA and Release. All changesets  have important info in description field which is a link to our helpdesk software in form of - RZ:issue_number; I'm trying to develop a console app which would get all issue numbers from all changesets that went into last team build. Build is based on Release branch. I have no issues getting this info from changesets directly checked in Release. But, QA gets merged into Release before build and those changesets have no description in Release branch. So, I planned to get linked changesets from merge action so I could read their description but I have not found a way how.

```
            var changes = buildKlijent.GetBuildChangesAsync("Argosy", build.Id).Result;

            foreach (var change in changes)
            {
                string komentar = change.Message;

                if (komentar.Contains("RZ:"))
                {
                    int start = komentar.IndexOf("RZ:") + 3;
                    int end = komentar.LastIndexOf(';');

                    string[] sirovirzovi = komentar.Substring(start, end - start).Split(new char[] { ',', ';' });
                    foreach (string rz in sirovirzovi)
                    {
                        int id;
                        if (int.TryParse(rz, out id))
                            radniZadaci.Rows.Add(id);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var changeSet = sourceKlijent.GetChangesetAsync(int.Parse(change.Id.Substring(1))).Result;
                    //TO DO: Get linked changeset from QA branch
                }
            }
```

So, my question boiles down to: Given a changeset ID and that changeset is created during a branch merge operation, how can I get linked changeset?

We're using TFS2015 server for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Changesets - Get Changeset Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get%20changeset%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) API to get `mergeSources` values. Then you'll see the linked changeset IDs.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is what I have been looking for.